# NoMethodError in Pages#profile

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm working on build a Twitter-like sample app, but I am stuck at creating a following method. I have created a Relationship model and the necessary classes to accomplish the task, but when I load the page, I receive the error "NoMethodError" on this line: `<%= form_for(current_user.active_relationships.build, remote: true) do |f| %>`

I render the form on the profile page like so:

```
<%= render '/components/follow_button', :user => User.find_by_username(params[:id]) %>
```

Here is the form:

```
<% if current_user.id != user.id %>
<div class="col s12">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <% if !current_user.following?(user) %>
            <%= form_for(current_user.active_relationships.build, remote: true) do |f| %>
                <div><%= hidden_field_tag :followed_id, user.id %></div>
                <%= f.submit "Follow", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
            <% end %>
        <% else %>
            <%= form_for(current_user.active_relationships.find_by(followed_id: user.id),
                html: { method: :delete }) do |f| %>
                <%= f.submit "Unfollow", class: "btn" %>
            <% end %>
        <% end %>
    </div>
</div>

<% end %>
```

User.rb:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  validates_uniqueness_of :email, :case_sensitive => false
  validates_uniqueness_of :username, :case_sensitive => false

    has_many :posts, dependent: :destroy
    has_many :active_relationships, class_name: "Relationship", foreign_key: "follower_id", dependent: :destroy
    has_many :passive_relationships, class_name: "Relationship", foreign_key: "followed_id", dependent: :destroy

    has_many :following, through: :active_relationships, source: :followed
    has_many :followers, through: :passive_relationships, source: :follower


    def follow(other)
      active_relationships.create(followed_id: other.id)
    end

    def unfollow(other)
      active_relationships.find_by(followed_id: other.id).destroy
    end

    def following?(other)
      following.include?(other)
    end

end
```

Relationship.rb

```
class Relationship < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :follower, class_name: "User"
    belongs_to :followed, class_name: "User"
    validates :follower_id, presence: true
    validates :followed_id, presence: true
end
```

RelationshipsController:

```
class RelationshipsController < ApplicationController

    def create
        user = User.find(params[:followed_id])
        current_user.follow(user)
        redirect_to(:back)
    end

    def destroy
        user = Relationship.find(params[:id]).followed
        current_user.unfollow(user)
        redirect_to(:back)
    end
end
```

Any help would be **greatly** appreciated.

**EDIT:** Following method used in Routes.rb

```
devise_for :users
  resources :users do
    member do
      get :following, :followers
    end
  end
```

Comment: What is the method that is undefined? Is it possibly `active_relationships` or `build` ? If so you can work backwards from here to figure out which object is not what you think it is.

Comment: I have been curious as to how it would connect with the method... I don't see build being defined anywhere, so maybe it has to do with that? The code I pasted above is all of it.

Comment: Can you paste the exact error that you got? For example: `NoMethodError: undefined method 'fake_method' for #<User:0x007fd604386440>` would tell me that I can't do `@user.fake_method`

Comment: Oh yes, my bad. `undefined method 'relationships_path' for #<#<Class:0x00000002203170>:0x00000003929ed0>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the [form_for](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.1/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-form_for) documentation, it eventually talks about 'Resource-oriented style' forms

> In the examples just shown, although not indicated explicitly, we still need to use the :url option in order to specify where the form is going to be sent. However, further simplification is possible if the record passed to form_for is a resource, i.e. it corresponds to a set of RESTful routes, e.g. defined using the resources method in config/routes.rb. In this case Rails will simply infer the appropriate URL from the record itself

```
<%= form_for(Post.new) do |f| %>
  ...
<% end %>
```

> is equivalent to something like:

```
<%= form_for @post, as: :post, url: posts_path, html: { class: "new_post", id: "new_post" } do |f| %>
  ...
<% end %>
```

Looking at your code, since you are not passing a `:url` option to `form_for` and you are passing an instance of a model, it's assuming your model was configured in the routes file with `resources :relationships`, which generates some named route helpers such as `relationships_path`, the method that it's complaining is missing.

To fix your problem, you need to pass `form_for` a `:url` where your controller lives and where it should post to, or update your routes to use the `resources :relationships`. You can read more information about the [resources routing here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#resource-routing-the-rails-default). If you add

```
resources :relationships, only: [:create, :destroy]
```

outside of your `devise_for` block, you'll end up with 2 new routes for

```
       Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                  Controller#Action
relationships POST   /relationships(.:format)     relationships#create
 relationship DELETE /relationships/:id(.:format) relationships#destroy
```

and the named helpers `relationships_path` and `relationship_path` which your 2 `form_for` tags are going to be looking for.

Don't forget to restart your server after making changes to your config/routes.rb file to make sure rails picks them up.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'm afraid I wouldn't know how to do that, as I am relatively new to Ruby. Would you mind editing my line and putting it here?

Comment: You haven't shown us what's in your config/routes.rb file, I could take a look and update my answer if you add that to your question, though that [second link I posted](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#resource-routing-the-rails-default) talks a lot about the purpose of the routes file and how to set up resource routes, and non-resource routes. I recommend giving it a read and seeing if that helps out at all.

Comment: Oops, good game. I did forget to include the routes.rb file. I knew something was amiss. It is now in my original post. I will also take a look at that link you pasted to understand it further.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. This is exactly what I needed and it taught me a bit about how it all works.